# Why does VS output lots of seemingly meaningless internal errors when I debug my application?

Tags: visual-studio, exception

Whenever I debug my app (MVC, .NET 6) out of Visual Studio (2022), the output window scrolls by with a bunch of exceptions, which I didn't seem to trigger, I can't seem to do anything about, and that don't seem to have any impact on the application.

For example:

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

I get a bunch of XML errors as well, out of internal .NET XML classes.

(For the record, I assume these are happening in the production deployment as well, they're just way more obvious to me when I debug in VS.)

Again, these don't seem to have any negative impact on the application.

What are these, and do I need to care about them?